# TYPO3 form: How to check equality between two email addresses?

Tags: forms, validation, email, typo3, equality

In the form extension I want to check two email fields for equality.
But there seems to be no validator to check two fields for equality: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/I/Concepts/Validators/Index.html

Has anyone already written a custom validator for this task?

Answer (score 0):

maybe that could be usefull: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/I/Concepts/Variants/Index.html

You can try to build an variant like "if email1 = email2 then go to next step, if not -> display error".

Or try to build your own validator.